# Next / previous posts link doesn't show up with Posts 2 Posts

Tags: wp-query, loop, next-post-link, paged

I am working on a Wordpress project where I use the [Posts 2 Posts](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki) plugin to show posts from one post type to posts from another post type.

This works great but for some reason my `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()` doesn't show up.

I have specified the `paged` variable in my code so it should work.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$connected = new WP_Query( array(
    'connected_type' => 'services_to_companies',
    'connected_items' => get_queried_object(),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 3
));

if ( $connected->have_posts() ) { ?>

<?php while ( $connected->have_posts() ) : $connected->the_post(); ?>

<div class="company_preview box_shadow">        
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>          
</div><!--End company_preview-->

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php if ( $connected->max_num_pages > 1 ) {
$current_page = $paged;
$total_pages = $connected->max_num_pages;
?>

<div id="nav-above">
    <div class="nav-next bx-next"><?php next_posts_link( 'Next &rarr;' ); ?></div>
    <div class="number"><?php echo $current_page . ' / ' . $total_pages; ?></div>
    <div class="nav-previous bx-prev"><?php previous_posts_link( '&larr; Previous' ); ?></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); } ?>
```

Comment: Have you read the Codex page for [`next_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query)?

Comment: Yes I did. But cannot find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From [`next_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query):

> Add the $max_pages parameter to the next_posts_link() function when querying the loop with WP_Query. To get the total amount of pages you can use the 'max_num_pages' property of the custom WP_Query object.

```
next_posts_link( 'Next &rarr;', $connected->max_num_pages );
```

Comment: Yes I have tried that, but doesn't work. The strange is that if I do /?page=2 nothing happens..

Comment: `page` and `paged` are not the same. what type of page do you have this code on? regardless, if you don't pass `max_num_pages`, it uses the value from an entirely different query.